# referencing subfigures with tufte-book and subfig package

Tags: subfloats, tufte

I can't figure out how to correctly reference subfigures with `tufte-book` class. Apparently it's NOT compatible with the `subcaption` package.

After a lot of googling, I tried:

- `subfigure`: all subfigures are correctly referenced, but it messes up the number (and link) of a lot of regular figures when I reference them.
- `subfig`: all links are correct, but subfigures are correctly referenced only with `\subref` (which outputs a letter) and not with `\ref` (it outputs `??`).

It seems easier to work with `subfig`, then. The only workaround I found is to combine `\ref` and `\subref` when I want to reference a subfigure.

Is there a less ugly solution?

Here's an example:

```
    \documentclass{tufte-book}
    \usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[t]
    \phantomsection
        \begin{subfloat}[Subfigure 1]
        {
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig1.eps}
        \label{fig:sub1}
        }
        \end{subfloat}
        \begin{subfloat}[Subfigure 2\label{fig:sub2}]
        { 
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig1.eps}
        }
        \end{subfloat}
        \caption{\protect\label{fig:results}Results for subfigure}
    \end{figure}

    We have Figure~\ref{fig:results} with a subfigure~\subref{fig:sub1} and~\subref{fig:sub2},
    or rather Figure~\ref{fig:sub1} and Figure~\ref{fig:sub2}.

    By combining the two, I get Figure~\ref{fig:results}\subref{fig:sub1} and Figure~\ref{fig:results}\subref{fig:sub2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `subfloat` environment with `subfig`, but a `\subfloat` command. And no, there's no “nice” solution for combining the cross references.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\phantomsection
\subfloat[Subfigure 1\label{fig:sub1}]
  {%
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig1.eps}%
  }

\subfloat[Subfigure 2\label{fig:sub2}]
  {%
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{subfig1.eps}%
  }

\caption{Results for subfigure\label{fig:results}}

\end{figure}

We have Figure~\ref{fig:results} with a subfigure~\subref{fig:sub1} 
and~\subref{fig:sub2},

By combining the two, I get Figure~\ref{fig:results}\subref{fig:sub1} and 
Figure~\ref{fig:results}\subref{fig:sub2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But does anything change with your modifications? The output is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @RickyRobinson Well, now the input is correct. `;-)`